# Which folder I have to move to start repo sync?

Tags: repo

I started syncing repo with the command ' $ repo sync -j4 '(without the quote). After downloading some data, I checked with th command ' ls -al' and could not find any .repo folder. I think I will have to go to my created folder named as cm12 and then start 'repo sync'. Am I right. I mean not to give command at " prasanna@prasanna-Aspire-4736Z " but at " prasanna@prasanna-Aspire-4736Z:~/cm12 ". Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform `repo` commands from any folder that's inside the repo-based directory

`repo` looks in the current folder for a `.repo` , and failing that, goes up a directory and so on to find the `.repo` folder.

When you first check out, it will (by default) create a folder, and you should run your commands from inside that folder (or any of the sub folders of it).

*As an aside, you might also be able to provide better help when asking your question through the use of the `pwd` command. When you say `prasanna@prasanna-Aspire-4736Z:~/cm12` thats showing part of your shell, and it might not show up what folder you are in (for lots of reasons, and looks different for lots of people). the command `pwd` returns your current working directory (it stands for 'Print Working Directory'.*